# snmpd.conf + snmp configuration

Tags: linux, redhat, snmp, snmpd

I have the following **snmpd.conf** ( this file is the same file on all 125 linux redhat machines , versions 5,6,7 )

```
more /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

dlmod cmaX /usr/lib64/libcmaX64.so
rocommunity sec999 127.0.0.1
rocommunity sec999 mach23
rocommunity sec999 mach98
rocommunity sec999 mach73
rocommunity sec999 mach74
syscontact mach76
syslocation UNKNOWN
```

in the file I have also the line - **/usr/lib64/libcmaX64.so**

but file

```
/usr/lib64/libcmaX64.so
```

actually isnt exist on all our machines !

so , is it safe to remove this line from the snmpd.conf file?

```
# ls /usr/lib64/libcmaX64.so
ls: /usr/lib64/libcmaX64.so: No such file or directory
```

SECOND

what is the meaning of - **dlmod cmaX .....**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can google it, and it will be a "dynamically loadable module" for
HP Proliant.
If you are running this on a HP Proliant, you'll probably need it.